# Android - RSS reader: URL forced to mobile address

Tags: android, rss

On the image you can see my origiginal URL for the RSS (http://www.fyens.dk/rss/sport) is changed to go to the mobile site (http://mobil.fyens.dk/modules/mobile). How can I avoid this? I can't read the RSS feed from the mobile site.

[image: From the debug:]

```
  try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.fyens.dk/rss/sport");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();


                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();


                Document document = db.parse(is);
                Element element = document.getDocumentElement();


                NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName("item");

                if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
```

The program jumps to a

```
catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

when it reaches the line

```
Document document = db.parse(is);
```

Comment: Can you share your code It is easy for us to know the actual problem.

Comment: sure, the program does not enter the parsing part, it jumps to the catch when it gets to the above line.

Comment: Have you added permissions ?

Comment: yes, I read the RSS from 3 other sites just above this code with no issues. I use the same code here - but the address is changed to the mobile version which is, of course, different from the one I use to get the RSS.

Comment: You can see on the image from android studio that the url of my inputstream is changed to the mobile address, really annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site is most likely doing a redirection based on User Agent. You want to fool the site with a different user agent string.

Try doing:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "The user agent you want to use");
```

You will want to use a user agent string that corresponds to a desktop browser. Check this list: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/